# How to loop through columns and update variable

Tags: javascript, arrays

Having scratched my head I am looking for a pointer in the right direction.
I have a google spreadsheet that has a number of rows.  Rows get added and the script looks at the newest row only.

Having no formal computer courses I am just picking things up, though in probably the most inefficient way possible.

I have a series of variables filled by the value of the cell, Data1, Data2 and so on till the row is complete iaw the number of columns.  It is only a single row, I dont want to process any more than 1 row.

Presently, I have coded to look at each one in turn :

```
var Data1 = sh.getRange(row,1).getValues()[0];
var Data2 = sh.getRange(row,2).getValues()[0];
var Data3 = sh.getRange(row,3).getValues()[0];
var Data4 = sh.getRange(row,4).getValues()[0];
```

and so on...

This is about as efficient as a kettle full of fish so was looking at arrays (if that is the solution) to loop through the row, a single row, and return an array that I can call on later on in some html, i.e...

```
<td width="443" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" colspan="3">' + Data1 + '</td><td width="245" b....
```

Can someone recommend me some examples where I can fully understand where an array can help, most examples seem to refer to 2D arrays but dont explain how to call the values thereafter...

Any help is welcome...

J

Answer (score 0):

An array in Javascript (and in other languages too) is a list of things, be it words (strings), numbers (int, float), or other arrays

It's sort of like an ordered box, where you have things placed one after the other.

Each item in the array has an "index" and we start counting from 0.

So the array:

```
var friut = ["apple", "banana", "orange"];
```

has three items with the index's 0, 1, & 2

by calling out the index's we can get the item from the array.

```
console.log( friut[0] ); //prints out "apple"

console.log( fruit[1] ); //prints out "banana"

console.log( friut[2] ); //prints out "orange"
```

Another property of arrays are "length", this way you can tell how many items are in your array.

```
console.log(friut.length()); //prints out 3, because there are three items in the array
```

so knowning how long an array is, we can use a loop to call out each item in the array

```
/* 
while "count" is less than the length of the array "fruit", perform an operation
and each time add 1 to count (thats the ++count part)
so when "count" reaches the same number as fruit.length(), stop
*/
for(var count = 0; count < friut.length(); ++count)
{
    console.log( friut[count] );
}
```

In this way you can replace the "console.log()" with a bit of script that draws an object on screen. 

REMEMBER, to get an element from an array you need to call it's index, which is just it's number in the list.

I hope that helps with the understanding a bit. 

As far as getting your data into an array you want to first create an array, then use the "push" command to set your data into it.

```
var dataArray = [];
dataArray.push( sh.getRange(row,1).getValues()[0] );
dataArray.push( sh.getRange(row,2).getValues()[0] );
dataArray.push( sh.getRange(row,3).getValues()[0] );
dataArray.push( sh.getRange(row,4).getValues()[0] );
```

then you can do:

```
for(var count = 0; count < dataArray.length(); ++count)
{
    document.write("<td width=\"443\" bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\" colspan=\"3\">" + dataArray[count] + "</td><td width=\"245\" b....");
}
```

Cheers!

...and here is a link to help with the nitty gritty details of an array...

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: Jason, many thanks for taking the time to explain, this does help a great deal.  Last question before I turn in for the night and dream of Java, using similar code can I loop through the pushing of data into the dataArray?  Some sheets may have 100 odd columns so, looping through the push seems more efficient....  Sorry to be a pain...

Comment: Yes, you can. If the data you get is in an array you can go ahead and loop over the source array and push into a new array...but if your data is already in an array why move it into a new one? Just loop your  source array and draw away all day!

Answer (score 0):

You also mention a 2D array.

This is simply an array of arrays.

Let's go back to fruit, lets say we have three arrays

```
var apples = ["gala", "washington", "fuji"];
var bananas = ["cavendish", "plantain", "lady finger"]
var oranges = ["valencia", "navel", "blood"];
```

and let's say we put these three lists in another list

```
var fruit = [apples, bananas, oranges];
```

So, now "fruit" is a list of three list. Or in the parlence  of Javascript, 
"fruit" is an array containing three arrays, or fruit is a 2D array.

Why 2D? Well if we draw it out we can see it lays out in 2 dimentions

```
fruit = 
---------------------------------------------
| "gala"       | "cavendish"   | "valencia" | 
| "washington" | "plantain"    | "navel"    | 
| "fuji"       | "lady finger" | "blood"    |
---------------------------------------------
```

Each entry can almost be thought of as points on an X,Y cooridnate plane (I'm totally going to catch some grief for this statement, but its good enough for a basic example).

```
"gala" is at (0,0)
"plaintain" is at (1,1)
"blood" is at (2,2)
```

REMEMBER we start our index counting at 0!
Low and behold! If we use this convention on the array fruit we can get a fruit out of the array

```
console.log( fruit[0][0] ); //prints gala
console.log( fruit[1][1] ); //prints plantain
console.log( fruit[2][2] ); //prints blood

console.log( fruit[0][2] ); //prints fuji
console.log( fruit[2][0] ); //prints valencia
```

Ok so a word of waring, this works great if all of your array's are the same size (length), but if they are not then you are going to have issues. Take a look

```
fruit = 
---------------------------------------------
| "gala"       | "cavendish"   | "valencia" | 
| "washington" | "lady finger" | "navel"    | 
| "fuji"       |               | "blood"    |
---------------------------------------------
```

Whow, "plaintain" is missing so if I tried to print the old address of "lady finger"

```
console.log( fruit[1][2] ); //no way! error town!
```

Javascript is going to complain. With "plaintain" gone, "lady finger" has a new index. These are the types of things that can screw you up until you know what to look for.

A bit long but I hope it helps.